# Populating treeview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I want populate a treeview in vb.net with the tablenames of the sql server and the column names of each table as the child nodes. May I know how to do this?

Comment: you should mention what you have tried and what your problem is! and codes!

Comment: Would help if you narrow down your question a bit more , i did post an answer below it may seem too general but its the best i could do with the little time i had since your question was too broad.

Comment: -1 No background, Technology using (WinForms\WPF, DataReaders\Entity\L2S), code...

Answer (score 2):

```
select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Gets all the Tables in Database on a single return table with each table as a new row

```
select COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = YOUR TABLE NAME
```

Gets all the columns in a Table on a single return table with each column name as a new row

I'll tell you the logic of adding tree nodes.

```
For each row as datarow in {select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES}
 Create TreeNode as new treenode with Text Row.column[0]
  For each innerrow as datarow in select {COLUMN_NAME
                                         from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                         where TABLE_NAME = row.column[0]}

     Create innertreenode as new treenode with Text innerrow.column[0]
     Add innertreenode to treenode.
  next

 Yourtreeview.nodes.add(treenode)
next
```

Note the above is not the actual code but the logic or the algorithm but the Queries for SQL is the actual code and im assuming you are not completely new to VB.net. In Vb.net actual code is going to be longer i.e with connection strings / Connecting to database , executing query and retrieving data to a table object and then adding data to tree-view control. What i just wrote was the basic logic to write it, Do some goggling on tree node properties and methods and if you don't know database connection strings / etc to parse the logic into actual code or ask below.

Comment: @user3422209 mark this post as ANSWER if it helped you to solve your problem.